# sql join tables with same column names

Tags: sql, sas

have table 1 and 2, how can I join them and create table 3? Seems neither left join nor union all would do the trick.
Thanks!

Table1

```
Key Var1 Var2

1    A    AA
2    B  
3    C  
4         DD
5         EE
```

Table2

```
Key Var1 Var2
3    C    CC
4    D    DD
5    E    EE
6    F    FF
7    G    GG
```

Table3

```
Key Var1 Var2
1    A    AA
2    B  
3    C    CC
4    D    DD
5    E    EE
```

Comment: Where did Key=6 and Key=7 rows go in the output?

Comment: key=6 and 7 are rows not wanted in the output.

Comment: Very cool! Both the top answer (by Gordon and Juergen) and the one by Vishant work. Any idea which is more efficient?

Answer (score 4):

Use `coalesce()` that returns the first non-null value

```
select t1.key,
       coalesce(t1.var1, t2.var1) as var1,
       coalesce(t1.var2, t2.var2) as var2
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
```

Comment: That's assuming that the blanks are nulls and not just empty strings.

Comment: @MatRichardson That's where it gets fun! `NULLIF(t1.var1, '')`

Answer (score 1):

The prior answer actually doesn't work correctly, as it uses an inner join:

```
select * from t1 where t1.key not in (select distinct key from t2) 
UNION
select * from t2 where key not in (select distinct key from t1)
UNION
select t1.key,
   coalesce(t1.var1, t2.var1) as var1,
   coalesce(t1.var2, t2.var2) as var2
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will do it in SAS,

```
/* The steps to create table 1 and 2 can be skipped if the Tables exist */
data table1;
  infile datalines dsd dlm=' ' missover;
  input Key Var1 $ Var2 $;
  datalines;
  1 A AA
  2 B  
  3 C  
  4  DD
  5  EE
  ;
run;

data table2;
  infile datalines  dsd dlm=' ' missover;
  input Key Var1 $ Var2 $;
  datalines;
  3 C CC
  4 D DD
  5 E EE
  6 F FF
  7 G GG
  ;
run;

/* Sort the Dataset T1 and T2 */
proc sort data=table1; by key; run;
proc sort data=table2; by key; run;

/* Final Output */
data want;
  merge table1(in=t1) table2(in=t2);
  by key;
  if t1; /* Keep only the records in Table 1 */
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

juergen hit the nail on the head.
however if you are dealing with empty strings instead of null substitute
     if(length(t1.var1) > 0, t1.var1,t2,var1) as var1,
     if(length(t1.var2) > 0, t1.var2,t2,var2) as var2,

coalesce is the preferred method. length check is slower

Answer (score 0):

I've re-created your question and wrote this query...

```
DECLARE @ta table (
id int,
var1 nvarchar(3),
var2 nvarchar(3)
)

DECLARE @tb table(
id int,
var1 nvarchar(3),
var2 nvarchar(3))

INSERT INTO @ta VALUES (1,'A','AA')
INSERT INTO @ta VALUES (2,'B','')
INSERT INTO @ta VALUES (3,'C','')
INSERT INTO @ta VALUES (4,'','DD')
INSERT INTO @ta VALUES (5,'','EE')

INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (3,'C','CC')
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (4,'D','DD')
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (5,'E','EE')
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (6,'F','FF')
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES (7,'G','GG')

SELECT id, var1, var2 from @ta where id <> (
SELECT a.id from @ta AS a INNER JOIN @tb AS b on a.var1 = b.var1)
AND var1 <> '' 
UNION 
SELECT id, var1, var2 from @tb
```

I wait, this code can help you...